# Android SQLite adding rows only once

Tags: android, sqlite

From what I understand, once a `SQL db` is created and populated it remains on the device until the app is uninstalled. For performance reasons I don't want to re insert all my rows every time the app is lauched, how can I wrap my insert statements so that I populated the db only the first time the app is launched?

Right now I have the inserts in the `onCreate()` method of my `main activity`. What is the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Insert your rows in onCreate method of `DatabaseHelper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your databases. Put your database creation and population code in the `onCreate()` of the helper - it gets invoked exactly once when the database file did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

before you could insert check for no of rows in the table. 
   `if(rows<1)
    {
    insertValues
    }
    else{
    //Do nothing //
    }`

you can get no of rows by using
    `int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,table_name);`